# Expected Homogenization Time

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume we have $N$ boxes, and each box contains one red sock and one blue sock. We can then perform the following process: randomly take one sock from each box and replace it with a red sock. What is the probability that all of the socks will be red after $n$ iterations of this procedure? And what is the expected number of times we would have to do this process in order to get all red socks?

Obviously, there's a $\dfrac{1}{2^N}$ probability of every sock being red after the first round, and a simple application of the Binomial Theorem shows that there's a $\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^N$ probability of having all red socks after $2$ iterations (this includes the case where all the socks are red after the first iteration). This might be a pattern, but I'm hesitant to conclude that based on a sample size of $2$. I tried writing a formula for higher numbers of iterations, but it looks pretty ugly.

PS: Yes, this is a subtly disguised genetics problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at one box.  After $n$ rounds, the probability of that box being red-blue is $\frac{1}{2^n}$.  So the probability of that box being red-red is $\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$.

Thus the probability of all $N$ boxes being red-red after $n$ rounds is $\left(\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\right)^N$.

For your second question, you can get a fairly good approximation of when you would expect all the boxes to be red-red, by noting that in each round you expect half the remaining red-blue boxes to switch to red-red.  So it should take about $\log_2 N$ rounds to get all the $N$ boxes to be red-red.

Comment: Hmm, so the pattern does hold! Great!